# Only one dashed line in a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem. I don't know how to get the top line of the triangle dashed. I already tried by drawing the line extra, but then the corners weren't clean.

That is my Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{tu}{RGB}{36,53,114}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
 \draw[line width=0.5mm, color=tu, fill=tu!40] (0,-4) -- node[sloped,below,color=black,font=\scriptsize] {Benutzeroberfläche}(3.5,2) 
    --node[sloped,above,color=black,font=\scriptsize,name=top]{transparentes Big-Data-Backend} (-3.5,2) -- node[sloped,below,color=black,font=\scriptsize] {Benutzeroberfläche} (0,-4) -- cycle;
%\draw[line width=0.5mm, color=tu, loosely dashed,] (3.5,2) -- node[sloped,above,color=black,font=\scriptsize,name=top]{transparentes Big-Data-Backend} (-3.5,2); 
 \node[name=center,align=center,text=white ]{\textbf{dreiseitige}\\\textbf{Koordinations-}\\\textbf{plattform}};
 \node [right=of center, align=center, name=right, font=\footnotesize] {\textbf{Nachfrage}\\(Auftraggeber)};
 \node [left=of center, align=center,name=left, font=\footnotesize] {\textbf{Angebot}\\(Auftragnehmer)}; 
 \node [above=0 of top, name=above, font=\footnotesize] {\textbf{Plattformbetreiber}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And it looks like this:[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposal: `line cap=round` and choose the `dash pattern` such that the start and end are `on`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{tu}{RGB}{0,53,128}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
 \fill[tu!40] (0,-4) -- node[sloped,below,color=black,font=\scriptsize] {Benutzeroberfläche}(3.5,2) 
    --node[sloped,above,color=black,font=\scriptsize,name=top]{transparentes Big-Data-Backend} (-3.5,2) -- node[sloped,below,color=black,font=\scriptsize] {Benutzeroberfläche} (0,-4) -- cycle;
 \draw[line width=0.5mm, color=tu,line cap=round] (-3.5,2) -- (0,-4) -- (3.5,2);
 \draw[line width=0.5mm, color=tu,dash pattern=on 0.7mm off 0.61mm,line cap=round] (-3.5,2) -- (3.5,2);
%\draw[line width=0.5mm, color=tu, loosely dashed,] (3.5,2) -- node[sloped,above,color=black,font=\scriptsize,name=top]{transparentes Big-Data-Backend} (-3.5,2); 
 \node[name=center,align=center,text=white ]{\textbf{dreiseitige}\\\textbf{Koordinations-}\\\textbf{plattform}};
 \node [right=of center, align=center, name=right, font=\footnotesize] {\textbf{Nachfrage}\\(Auftraggeber)};
 \node [left=of center, align=center,name=left, font=\footnotesize] {\textbf{Angebot}\\(Auftragnehmer)}; 
 \node [above=0 of top, name=above, font=\footnotesize] {\textbf{Plattformbetreiber}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you want regular dashes:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\definecolor{tu}{RGB}{36,53,114}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
 \fill[tu!40] (0,-4) -- node[sloped,below,color=black,font=\scriptsize] {Benutzeroberfläche}(3.5,2) 
    --node[sloped,above,color=black,font=\scriptsize,name=top]{transparentes Big-Data-Backend} (-3.5,2) -- node[sloped,below,color=black,font=\scriptsize] {Benutzeroberfläche} (0,-4) -- cycle;
 \draw[line width=0.5mm, color=tu,line cap=round] (-3.5,2) -- (0,-4) -- (3.5,2);
 \draw[line width=0.5mm, color=tu,dash pattern=on 3pt off 2.1pt,
 Round Cap-Round Cap] (-3.5,2) -- (3.5,2);
%\draw[line width=0.5mm, color=tu, loosely dashed,] (3.5,2) -- node[sloped,above,color=black,font=\scriptsize,name=top]{transparentes Big-Data-Backend} (-3.5,2); 
 \node[name=center,align=center,text=white ]{\textbf{dreiseitige}\\\textbf{Koordinations-}\\\textbf{plattform}};
 \node [right=of center, align=center, name=right, font=\footnotesize] {\textbf{Nachfrage}\\(Auftraggeber)};
 \node [left=of center, align=center,name=left, font=\footnotesize] {\textbf{Angebot}\\(Auftragnehmer)}; 
 \node [above=0 of top, name=above, font=\footnotesize] {\textbf{Plattformbetreiber}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]